# pandas get rows from one dataframe which are existed in other dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes. The dataframes as follows:

```
df1 is
          numbers
user_id 
0         9154701244
1         9100913773
2         8639988041
3         8092118985
4         8143131334
5         9440609551
6         8309707235
7         8555033317
8         7095451372
9         8919206985
10        8688960416
11        9676230089
12        7036733390
13        9100914771

it's shape is (14,1)

df2 is

        user_id         numbers        names    type        duration    date_time
0       9032095748      919182206378   ramesh   incoming    23          233445445
1       9032095748      918919206983   suresh   incoming    45          233445445
2       9032095748      919030785187   rahul    incoming    45          233445445
3       9032095748      916281206641   jay      incoming    67          233445445
4       jakfnka998nknk  9874654411     query    incoming    25          8571228412
5       jakfnka998nknk  9874654112     form     incoming    42          678565487
6       jakfnka998nknk  9848022238     json     incoming    10          89547212765
7       ukajhj9417fka   9984741215     keert    incoming    32          8548412664
8       ukajhj9417fka   9979501984     arun     incoming    21          7541344646
9       ukajhj9417fka   95463241       paru     incoming    42          945151215451
10      ukajknva939o    7864621215     hari     outgoing    34          49829840920

and it's shape is (10308,6)
```

Here in df1, the column name numbers are having the multiple unique numbers. These numbers are available in df2 and those are repeated depends on the duration. I want to get those data who all are existed in df2 based on the numbers which are available in df1.

Here is the code I've tried to get this but I'm not able to figure it out how it can be solved using pandas.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]) # concat dataframes
df = df.reset_index(drop=True) # reset the index
df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns)) #group by
idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1] #reindex
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

It gives me only unique numbers column which are there in df2. But I need to get all the data including other columns from the second dataframe.

It would be great that anyone can help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample dataframe, I created keeping the gist same.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"numbers":[123,1234,12345,5421]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"numbers":[123,1234,12345,123,123,45643],"B":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"C":[2,3,4,5,6,7]})

final_df=df2[df2.numbers.isin(df1.numbers)]
```

**Output DataFrame** The result is all unique numbers that are present in `df1` and present in `df2` will be returned

```
   numbers  B  C
0      123  1  2
1     1234  2  3
2    12345  3  4
3      123  4  5
4      123  5  6
```